# React router 3.0.2 + es6: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

While rewriting some components in es6 syntax my React router started throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Navicon`.
```

This error only springs if I include a `<Link>` component inside my Navicon component, which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router';
import './navicon.css';

class Navicon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='navicon-container' tabIndex='0'>
        <div className={'dropdown'}>
          <Link to={'/'}>Hello</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navicon;
```

The component that mounts my router looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import './main.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App}>
      <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I'm using `"react-router": "^3.0.2"`

Does anyone have any idea what might be tripping this error? This error never sprang when I was using `React.createClass()`, so I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it seems that due to the export syntax on react router components, one evidently must use:

```
// import Link from react-router   <- this doesn't work
import {Link} from react-router // <- this does
```

That little change resolves the error.